# Symfony 2 finding blog posts for multiple users

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 tables: `user`, `user_followers` and `blog_posts`.
Users can follow other users and users are related to `blog_post` by `user_id`.

I need to get all blog posts that people I follow have written.
I tried something like:

```
$followedUsers = $user->getFollowedByMe(); //This one works
$posts = $entityManager->getRepository('<BundleHere>:BlogPosts')
                       ->findBy(array('user_id' => $followedUsers));
```

And I tried a lot more variations but can't figure it out. Maybe someone knows a better way to search by multiple objects not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out (thanx guys for pointing me in the right direction with queryBuilder).

```
$followedByMe = $user->getFollowedByMe(); //Getting users i follow
$followedIds = $followedByMe
->map(function( $obj ) { //Using map method to create an array of id's for all followers
    return $obj->getId(); //Value to put into array (in this case id)
})->toArray(); //Create an array and assign it to $followedIds variable

$qb = $em->getRepository('<BundleHere>:BlogPosts')->createQueryBuilder('b');
$posts = $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('b.user', $followedIds ))
->orWhere('b.user = :my_id')->setParameter('my_id', $user->getId()) //Get my posts too
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of code in your BlogRepository.php in example.

```
public function getBlogPost($userId)
{
    return $this
        ->_em
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.user', 'u')
        ->where('u.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

createQueryBuilder('p') will automatically create the select and from (select entity (post ?) from table).
Then, you can use it like this :

```
$posts = $entityManager->getRepository('<BundleHere>:BlogPosts')->getBlogPost($userId);
```

I can't give you the exact query because we don't have enough informations about your entities. But this way, you can write nice queries to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$posts = $entityManager->getRepository('<BundleHere>:BlogPosts')
    ->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->whereIn('b.user', $followedUsers)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

'user' should be the name of property used to hold the user in the Blogpost object.